# How to use Evaluate instead of for each Loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to know How to use `Evaluate` instead of  for each Loop ?  as in below simple code:

```
Sub Loop_Range_2()
 
Dim cel As Range, counter As Long
 
For Each cel In Range("A1:D5")
   counter = counter + 1
    cel = counter
Next
 
End Sub
```

In advance, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `For Each...Next` vs `Worksheet.Evaluate` vs `Array`

- Here is a benchmark setup that shows that using an array is in general the most efficient way.
- I only could figure out an *Evaluate* version by looping through the rows of the range and using `ROW` function. Note its limitation of 1048576 rows (1024*1024 or 10^20) . The fewer rows, the faster the solution. At the current setup, it is even more efficient than the array version.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Const rCount As Long = 64
Private Const cCount As Long = 16384
Private dT As Double


Sub Loop_Range_2()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
  
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").Resize(rCount, cCount)
    
dT = Timer
    
    Dim cel As Range, n As Long
     
    For Each cel In rg.Cells
        n = n + 1
        cel.Value = n
    Next
 
Debug.Print "For Each...Next Loop = " & Format(Timer - dT, "00.000000") _
    & vbTab & rCount & vbTab & cCount
End Sub


Sub EvaluateRow()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
  
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").Resize(rCount, cCount)
    
    Dim rrg As Range, c As Long
    
dT = Timer
    
    For Each rrg In rg.Rows
        c = c + 1
        rrg.Value = Application.Transpose(ws.Evaluate( _
            "ROW(" & (c - 1) * cCount + 1 & ":" & c * cCount & ")"))
    Next rrg

Debug.Print "Evaluate Row         = " & Format(Timer - dT, "00.000000") _
    & vbTab & rCount & vbTab & cCount
End Sub


Sub ArrayLoop()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").Resize(rCount, cCount)
    Dim Data() As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, n As Long
    
Dim dT As Double: dT = Timer
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        For c = 1 To cCount
            n = n + 1
            Data(r, c) = n
        Next c
    Next r
    
    rg.Value = Data
    
Debug.Print "Array Loop           = " & Format(Timer - dT, "00.000000") _
    & vbTab & rCount & vbTab & cCount
End Sub
```